# Weird jQuery bug when creating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Check it out

```
var q = $('<div> test 1 </div>');

$('body').append(q);

q = $('<div> test 2 </div>');
```

the page prints "test 1" !! Why?

Comment: Did You append q when you changed it on the 3rd line ?

Comment: no but why do I have to if I did it before?

Comment: Because q is not attached or bound to the DOM, when you change q there is no framework available like backbone or angular that would have created a listener whenever q changes update the DOM. Jquery is a library that does work in less syntax :)

Comment: `q` is just a variable. Changing the variable's value doesn't affect things that you did with the previous value.

Comment: Most popular programming languages are pass by value. JavaScript is not any different here. It's certainly not a bug in jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Assigning to a variable doesn't affect the data that was previously assigned to the variable. If you want to change the DOM, you have to modify the object that the variable refers to, not the variable.

```js
var q = $('<div> test 1 </div>');
$('body').append(q);
q.text(' test 2 ');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```